# Remove rows containing a period at the start and end in R

Tags: r, regex, character, match, rows

I have a dataset in R with over a hundred rows of characters.

I'm trying to remove all rows that start and end in a '.' period character. 
 I would first set these rows to blanks and then removing them later by writing them to a .csv file.  The issue is in the first part, how do I first set them to blanks?

Below are gsub commands that I tried, but do not do anything to any row.

```
#remove all periods followed by a space
data$text<- gsub('^([.][.])$', '', data$text)
data$text <- gsub('[.]*$',"",data$text) # with over a hundred rows

Value   text
1     male occupied
2     male occupied
3     female occupied
4     . . . .
5     male occupied
6     . . .
7     female occupied
8     . .
```

My expected output:

```
Value   text
1     male occupied
2     male occupied
3     female occupied
5     male occupied
7     female occupied
```

How can I do this in R?  Is gsub the way to go?

Comment: Try `df1[!grepl("^\\.|\\.$", df1$text),]`  Instead of `gsub`, use `grep` to find the rows having thee required pattern and remove it

Comment: @akrun I think the OP wants BOTH conditions - not one or the other.

Comment: @GSW in that case `df1[!grepl("^\\..*\\.$", df1$text),]`

Comment: @akrun As far as my googling goes, I have seen solutions use both gsub and grep.  Does anyone know if there was a reason/why that grep was used instead in this case?  Both can do pattern matching and replacement.  `data$text[!grepl("^\\..*\\.$", data$text),]` solved both problems.

 I would like to mark your submission as an answer, if you could repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` is global substitution to remove/replace substring from a string.  According to `?gsub`

> The two *sub functions differ only in that sub replaces only the first occurrence of a pattern whereas gsub replaces all occurrences.

Here, the intention is to find the location of the pattern in a vector and remove those elements in a vector or column (to remove rows from a data.frame).  The `grep` documentation says

> grep, grepl, regexpr, gregexpr and regexec search for matches to argument pattern within each element of a character vector: they differ in the format of and amount of detail in the results.

So, we get the numeric index (`grep`) or logical vector (`grepl`) output and subset the ddata

```
df1[!grepl("^\\.|\\.$", df1$text),]
```

Here, we match a `.` (`.` is a metacharacter for any character - so to get the literal meaning, either escape (`\\`) or place it in square bracket (`[.]`) or use `fixed = TRUE` - here there is `|`, so we can't uses that option)  at the start (`^`) or end (`$`) of string to return a logical vector with `grepl`, negate (`!`) so that TRUE -> FALSE, and FALSE -> TRUE and use it to filter the rows.